# Issue while getting the latest record by time from cosmos database

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I worked on simple web application, in that I used the cosmos database to save some data into it. Up to now everything working fine. But whenever I am trying to get the latest value by time from cosmos database, then it’s take more than one minute to give the latest record.

This is the code I wrote for getting the latest record from cosmos database.

```
        public static async Task<IEnumerable<IoTHubDataPoint>> GetItemsAsync()
    {
        IDocumentQuery<IoTHubDataPoint> query = client.CreateDocumentQuery<IoTHubDataPoint>(
            UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(DatabaseId, CollectionId),               
            new FeedOptions { MaxItemCount = 1, EnableCrossPartitionQuery = true}).OrderByDescending(x=>x.Time).Take(1)
            .AsDocumentQuery();

        List<IoTHubDataPoint> results = new List<ServiceMaxIoTHubDataPoint>();
        while (query.HasMoreResults)
        {
            results.AddRange(await Task.Run(async () => await query.ExecuteNextAsync<IoTHubDataPoint>()) );
        }
        //return results.OrderByDescending(x => x.Time).Take(1).ToArray();
        return results;

    }
```

This is the sample data avaialble inside the azure cosmos database.

```
{
"DeviceID": "IoT-1",
"Time": "2017-11-02T14:46:06.7846161",
"Temperature": 28.63403,
"Pressure": "95089.47",
"Altitude": "532.5873",
"LightStatus": "Too Bright",
"LightCDSValue": "193",
"LightCDSVoltageValue": "0.943304",
"EventProcessedUtcTime": "2017-11-02T14:46:40.3930989Z",
"PartitionId": 0,
"EventEnqueuedUtcTime": "2017-11-02T14:46:07.6Z",
"IoTHub": {
    "MessageId": null,
    "CorrelationId": null,
    "ConnectionDeviceId": "IoT-1",
    "ConnectionDeviceGenerationId": "636449561753440920",
    "EnqueuedTime": "2017-11-02T14:46:07.826Z",
    "StreamId": null
},
"id": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
"_rid": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXx",
"_self": "dbs/4RM3AA==/colls/4RM3AOJ1XQA=/docs/XXXXXXXXXXXx==/",
"_etag": "\"XXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXx\"",
"_attachments": "attachments/",
"_ts": XXXXXX
}
```

Can anyone please tell me how to resolve the above issue?

Comment: It looks like you are retrieving your complete table before you pick the most recent. Of course that takes a lot of time if your table is not very small. I don't know cosmosdb, but I'm used to databases that can do this work server-side, preferably using an index.

Comment: Not only returning all results: if you have multiple partitions, this is a complete fan-out query, so all results from all partitions.

Comment: @DavidMakogon, I have 5000 records in my cosmos db. Then how can I get the latest record from cosmos db.

Comment: @pradeep - That's what your query is for. But you haven't written any query, aside from the equivalent of `"select * from collection"`.  You haven't provided any details of your data, but I'm guessing you have some type of timestamp property you could order by, and then return only the latest.

Comment: @DavidMakogon, what ever you are thinking that only I implemented in my application but I used LINQ query not an SQL query.

Comment: Please try the following query: `IDocumentQuery<IoTHubDataPoint> query = client.CreateDocumentQuery<IoTHubDataPoint>(
            UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(DatabaseId, CollectionId),
            new FeedOptions { MaxItemCount = 1, EnableCrossPartitionQuery = true }).OrderBy(x => x.Time)
            .AsDocumentQuery();`

Comment: @GauravMantri, I think you could turn your comment to an answer - just use OrderByDescending and then you could also considering moving the Take(1) as well from results fitlering to your querying logic. I don't think there's anything more to this question.

Comment: @GauravMantri, Please see my updated question once, I already write the above lines of code, but I am not getting the latest record. It gives results count is 0

Comment: @GauravMantri, I am getting the results when I used Temperature property instead of Time. Can you please tell me where did i mistake in my above code.

Comment: You probably don't need the .Take(1) since you already specified a max document count.  Also, you could try specifying your partition key and turning off the cross partition query.  That will speed it up significantly.

Comment: Thanks @JakeJ, can you give me the example of how to write the query based on your above comment.

Comment: Just disable the cross partition query in your feed options (change that to false or just leave that out entirely) and add whatever you named your partition key to your query string.  There are methods like that one where you can feed in a query string as well.
client.CreateDocumentQuery<T>(UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(DatabaseId, CollectionId), queryString, new FeedOptions { MaxItemCount = 300, EnableCrossPartitionQuery = false })

In query string you'll have your SQL statement with the where clause including the partition key column and the value of the partition key.

Comment: Something like "SELECT * FROM yourTableNameHere WHERE partitionKey = ValueOfPartitionKeyHere"
It's a SQL select command.  If I'm a little off, check out the sql API stuff in Cosmos DB docs.

Answer (score 5):

Here is the query you can execute in Azure `SELECT top 1 * FROM c order by c._ts desc`

Comment: The moment we add order by the query becomes extremely slow.

Comment: @inquisitive Azure recommends setting up Composition indexes for queries containing order by https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/how-to-manage-indexing-policy?tabs=dotnetv2%2Cpythonv3#composite-index-defined-for-name-asc-age-desc